# Problem with create list using for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, list, for-loop, count

I'm trying to crate a code that will count number of images I have and then will create a list with the number of images (for example, if I have 5 images, I'll get this :
[0,1,2,3,4].

My code runs and I think it creates a list that is empty:
[image]

This is my code (I have tried to put only the relevant part):

```
//First I filter my image collection according to the number of pixels each image has
//Filter according to number of pixels

var ndviWithCount = withNDVI.map(function(image){
  var countpixels = ee.Number(image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: geometry,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 30,
  }).get('NDVI'));

  return image.set('count', countpixels);
});

print(ndviWithCount, 'ndviWithCount');

//Here I count what is the maximum number of pixels that image has and then I create new collection with //only "big images"

var max = ndviWithCount.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.max(),  ["count"]);
print(max.get('max'));
var max_pix=max.get('max');

//filter between a range
var filter = ndviWithCount.filter(ee.Filter.rangeContains(
          'count', max_pix, max_pix));
print(filter, 'filtered');
//Here I try to grab the number of images so I can create a list
var num_images=filter.size();

//creating the list of images

var listOfImages =(filter.toList(filter.size()));

//Here is the loop that diesn't work
//I have tried to determine i=0, and then that it will iterate untill i is equal to the number of images
//I try to say, i=0, so add 1 and the nadd it to my list.
for (i = 0; i < num_images; i++) {
  var listOfNumbers=[];
  i=i.add(1);
  listOfNumbers.push(i);

}
```

my end goal is to have list that contains nmbers from 0 or 1 to the number of images I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The reason for the error is because of the GEE envorinment.
This code works:

```
var serverList = ee.List.sequence(0,NumberOfImages.subtract(1));
serverList = serverList.map(function(n) {
  return ee.Number(n).add(1);
});
print(serverList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < num_images; i++) {
  var listOfNumbers=[];
  i=i.add(1);
  listOfNumbers.push(i);
}
```

You are initiating the array inside the for loop which isn't what you intend. I'm also not sure what i = i.add(1) is supposed to be. May be helpful to check out info on [for loops](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

```
let listOfNumbers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < num_images; i++) {
      listOfNumbers.push(i);
}
```

Comment: with i+1 I have tried to do something similar to something I know to do in python, which is , fount for loop, so whenever i is equal to a number that I define (like the maximum) it will stopthe for loop.

Comment: all of that is taken care of in the top level statement: let i = 0; i < num_images [this runs the for loop as long as i is less than num_images. and the i++ at the top adds i after each run of the loop.

Comment: when I use your code I get error message SyntaxError: Unexpected token (4:4). I have tried to creaate list like that also wothout my code and get the same error

Comment: you make have an issue with lexical scope (e.g you have already declared "listOfNumbers" somewhere). Here is a working online [REPL](https://repl.it/repls/TurboEllipticalDecagon) showing for loop.